# Luxon is Changing the Dates to Browser Local

Tags: javascript, datetime, luxon

Luxon date object is using the browser local date when I am converting to the native JS date object. Is there a way to convert the Luxon date to JS date without losing the timezone?

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const d = DateTime.fromISO('2020-08-01T18:45', {zone: 'America/Chicago'});
console.log(d);
console.log(d.toJSDate());
```

Here is link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/temurih/9jat1w4q/7/)

```js
const DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
const d = DateTime.fromISO('2020-08-01T18:45', {
  zone: 'America/Chicago'
});
console.log(d);
console.log(d.toJSDate());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.16.0/build/global/luxon.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you convert both the Luxon and the JS objects to iso/utc strings do they have the same value?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky No they do not. https://jsfiddle.net/temurih/9jat1w4q/9/

Comment: "JS Dates" do not have a timezone. They are internally UTC and use system settings to get and apply the offset for "local" values so no, you can't keep the timezone when converting to Date object. You can keep the offset if you use a timestamp such as ISO 8601 YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss±HH:mm but that loses the context like "Europe/Berlin" or whatever the IANA location was.

Comment: @RobG If you do `new Date`, it does contain the timezone, `Sun Aug 01 2021 23:23:22 GMT-0600`, how can I change `-0600`, if I can? The problem with just time offset is that someone can do `toUTCString()` and it will give them the previous/next date depending on the timezone `-0600`. I want to avoid that.

Comment: @HafizTemuri—the offset in the timestamp generated by *toString* comes from the system, the date itself is just an offset from the ECMAScript epoch, UTC. Change the offset in system settings and you'll see a different offset in the timestamp.

Comment: E.g. if you do `new Date('Sun Aug 01 2021 23:23:22 GMT-0600')` then a [*time value*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-time-values-and-time-range) is generated that is an offset from the epoch UTC. That is the sole settable data property of a [*Date* instance](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-properties-of-date-instances), there is no instance or inherited value for timezone, only [*getTimezoneOffset*](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.gettimezoneoffset) which is calculated from system settings for the particular date and time.

Comment: So basically you are saying it's not possible to change the timezone value since it's system generated. And if I do time offset, someone can run `toUTCString()` which will screw up the dates, and there is no way around it.